# Protecting views, authentication or canActivate for Angular 2 with ui-router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, typescript2.0

I thought I could try using `ui-router` with Angular 2.

Currently, I already have some default `angular2-router` configuration, which mostly comes down to something like:

```
export const homeRoute: Route = {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
};
```

`ui-router` docs shows a similar example, [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng2.html):

```
export let state1: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
  name: 'state1',
  component: State1Component,
  url: '/one'
}
```

Which would do just fine, but for one missing key: `canActivate`.

In Angular 1 I have used a great lib: [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission) but it is not available for Angular 2.

I do not need fancy permissions at the moment, a simple true/false authentication would do, however, I simply do not know how to protected my routes.

I have tried searching but the topic is so fresh, there are no examples available.

Thanks for all the ideas.

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use `TransitionService.onBefore()` as described in the [API doc](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onbefore). This class is part of the `ui-router-core` package shared between Angular 1 & 2. It is a direct replacement of `$transitions` in Angular 1.

Simply put, use

```
TransitionService.onBefore({to: 'requiresAuth.*'}, (transition: Transition) => {
    let auth = transition.injector().get(YourOwnAuthService);
    if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        return transition.router.stateService.target('login');
    }
    return true;
});
```

One can extract the callback to a `function checkAuthentication(transition: Transition): boolean` and apply this function to multiple base states. For example,

```
['dashboard.*', 'report.*', 'sale.*'].forEach(state => {
     TransitionService.onBefore({to: state}, checkAuthentication);
});
```

This code snippet can be placed right below your ui-router state definitions.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to offer you a PoC app that implements just that. Please find it directly from Github as the code may be too much for the message box.

**LoggedInGuard** ("*/app/shared/guards/logged-in.guard.ts*")
https://github.com/AFigueroa/angular2-poc/blob/master/app/shared/guards/logged-in.guard.ts

**AppRoutingModule** ("*/app/app-routing.module.ts*")
https://github.com/AFigueroa/angular2-poc/blob/master/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: but it uses native `angular2-router` and I need a solution for `ui-router`

Comment: So just to understand your question, you need a way to block access if the user's loggedIn value is set to false, on AngularJS (v1) using ui-router?